# JQuery change html content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a right sidebar that slides out and shows content. The sidebar can be opened from multiple buttons (button1, button2, button3, etc.) The content needs to be different in the sidebar when certain buttons are clicked? What is the most efficient way to do this? I tried using .html() but it overrides the styles. For example, if the content triggered by button1 is "Test" and button2 shows "Test2", if I click button1 again, it'll show "Test2". Is there a way to efficiently maintain consistency of data across each click event?

Comment: modify the class of a common container, use css to show/hide based on the class.

Comment: Personally, when I created side panels, I created tabs with IDs. When the tabs were clicked, I checked the IDs, and used AJAX to load content based on the ID clicked. However, if you know what the content is going to be, and is static, you can skip the AJAX part.

Comment: @dandavis Will this get bloated? If I have say 12 buttons? I feel like I'd have 11 .hide()'s and 1 .show() for each button? If so, then thats totally ok!

Comment: @TurdPile Yes, the content is static! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  var value = this.getAttribute('data-dynamicContent');
  document.getElementById('dynamicContent').innerHTML = value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" data-dynamicContent="This is your content" value="button one">
<input type="button" data-dynamicContent="This is your content 2" value="button two">
<input type="button" data-dynamicContent="This is your content 3" value="button three">
<div id="dynamicContent"></div>
```

Here is one that isn't as clean but offers better browser support:

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  document.getElementById('dynamicContent').innerHTML = this.name;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="your content one" value="button one">
<input type="button" name="your content two" value="button two">
<input type="button" name="your content three" value="button three">
<div id="dynamicContent"></div>
```

Here is one that has more code but has the best browser support:

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  document.getElementById('dynamicContent').innerHTML = this.nextElementSibling.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="button one">
  <input type="hidden" value="your content one">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="button" value="button two">
  <input type="hidden" value="your content two">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="button" value="button two">
  <input type="hidden" value="your content three">
</div>

<div id="dynamicContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/2mmvjf9c/

```
$('button').click(function(){
   console.log($(this)[0].innerText)
    if($(this)[0].innerText === "button 1"){
      $('span').html('test 1')
    } else  if($(this)[0].innerText === "button 2"){
      $('span').html('test 2')
    }else{
    $('span').html('test 3')
    }
})
```